# Problems calling Facebook with Angular $resource

Tags: express, angular-resource

If I use a simple button with href="users/facebook" in the login form, the facebook callback works fine.

I want to change it so that a service function calls "users/facebook" but it is not working. I now have:

login.html

```
<a href="" ng-click="facebookLogin()" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
```

controllers.js

```
$scope.facebookLogin = function() {
        console.log('facebookLogin called');
        AuthFactory.facebookLogin();
    };
```

services.js

```
authFac.facebookLogin = function() {
      console.log('in services/facebooklogin');
      $resource(baseURL + "users/facebook").get(function(){
    });
    };
```

routes/users.js

```
//not working
    router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'),
      function(req, res){
        console.log('facebook called');
      });
```

According to the console the $resource call to "https://localhost:3443/users/facebook" works ok but the router.get('/facebook) is not working.
I can't see what's going wrong.

edit:

Postman `GET https://localhost:3443/users/facebook` works perfectly so I can't understand why `$resource(baseURL + "users/facebook").get(function()` isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd taken care of CORS by adding the following to my server file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
  next();
});
```

But it was still an issue which in the end was only fixed by using:

```
window.location = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/users/facebook';
```

instead of:

```
$resource(baseURL + "users/facebook")
```

now the facebookCallback function works.